# What methods are used to encrypt passwords in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow?

Tags: password, hashsum

A careful examination of the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files reveal that the passwords stored are hashed using some form of hashing function.

A quick Google search reveals that by default, the passwords are encrypted using [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard). If an entry begins with `$`, then it indicates that some other hashing function was used.

For example, some entries on my Ubuntu machine begin with `$6$`...

What do the various numbers represent?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The full list is in `man 5 crypt` ([web version](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/libcrypt-dev/crypt.5.en.html)):

| Prefix | Hashing Method |
| --- | --- |
| "$y$" | yescrypt |
| "$gy$" | gost-yescrypt |
| "$7$" | scrypt |
| "$2b$" | bcrypt |
| "$6$" | sha512crypt |
| "$5$" | sha256crypt |
| "$sha1" | sha1crypt |
| "$md5" | SunMD5 |
| "$1$" | md5crypt |
| "_" | bsdicrypt (BSDI extended DES) |
| (empty string) | bigcrypt |
| (empty string) | descrypt (Traditional DES) |
| "$3$" | NT |

(Blowfish can be either `$2$` or `$2a$` according to [Wikipedia Crypt (Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(Unix)).)

So `$6$` means `SHA-512`.

Which one your system uses is governed by any options passed to the [pam_unix PAM module](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_unix.html).

The default on the latest version of Ubuntu is set in `/etc/pam.d/common-password`:

```
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

which means that next time you change your password, it will be hashed using SHA-512, assuming your account is local, rather than NIS/LDAP/Kerberos, etc.

See also:

- [FreeBSD crypt](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/crypt.html)
- [ArchLinux Blowfish passwords](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Blowfish_passwords)
- [NetBSD crypt(3)](http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/crypt.3.html)
- [PHP crypt function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

Comment: A quick double check of my `/etc/shadow` shows 2 entries that start with `$6$`.

Comment: Note that SHA-256 and SHA-512 are part of the SHA-2 set of hash functions.

Comment: Note that the crypt hashes based on SHA-2 are not plain SHA-2, which would be bad since plain SHA-2 is weak against dictionary attacks. The SHA-2 crypt schemes use the plain hashes as building block, but add a variable work-factor(to slow down dictionary attacks) and a salt.

Comment: In my Ubuntu machine, root's password has an exclamation mark symbol (`!`). Reading `man shadow`, it means that the password is locked, so you can't log in directly using unix password. It has to do with Ubuntu set root account disabled by default.